# show dialogbox from item litsview and edittext

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, dialog

Please help me. Basically I want this to pop up / dialog box when the user clicks an item from listview. DialogBox include edittext and item listview. Thank you

Here is my code MainActivity.class, working to showing toast.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialize();

        btnkl.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnhps.setOnClickListener(this);

        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        String[] satu = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.quotes);      
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, satu));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);

@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
    }
```

Comment: is Dailog box same for all listitem....

Comment: not same, dialogbox just show on Item click

Answer (score 0):

There is a detailed tutorial about using dialogs at [Android Developer: Dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

The easiest way is to build an AlertDialog with a Custom Layout, that shows your desired ListView and EditText.

```
// 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

// 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message)
       .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title)

//Use your custom layout (f.e. by findViewByID(custom_dialog_layout));
.setView(custumLayout);

// 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
```

Comment: could you kindly show your code more details about my case. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If You Use Same Dailog For all List Item then,

You have to just Create the progress Dailog in OnItemClick Listner.Then Create one xml(Layout) File That contain edittext and the your list item(as per your requirement),then set this file to your dialog using setcontentview method.below is the example.

```
   Dialog dialog=new Dialog(context);
   dialogSort.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_sort);
   dialog.show();
```

Comment: final Dialog about = new Dialog(context);
   about.setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
   about.setTitle("About");     
   TextView text = (TextView) about.findViewById(R.id.textdialogresoult);
   text.setText("TextView") // I want To getText from EditText Input